# How can I clear photos from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, photo-stream, image-capture

I'm trying to delete my camera roll, I imported in to iPhoto, then deleted all the photos with Image Capture. As soon as I open the Photos app on the iPhone it just starts downloading everything again... Any ideas? I'd like to keep my photo stream working, just not keep the whole camera roll on the phone.

Comment: You could turn off Photo Stream to see if the stream is downloading the photos to your device. If so, you'll have to prune your stream from the computer or another iOS device before re-enabling the stream. Is this what you seek?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure what you're seeing is actually Camera Roll and not Photo stream.

1. Tap Settings > General > Usage.
2. Wait for the "Storage" section at the top to populate (can take a
   while).
3. Tap "Photos & Camera".
4. Tap "Camera Roll".

This will display the usage for each section. If it's Photo Stream then you have your answer. If it's actually the Camera Roll re-populating then you should check iTunes and make sure that "Sync Photos from" is unchecked.

[image: iTunes screenshot]

If it was checked, uncheck it and do a sync again. That should clear it out.

Answer (score 0):

personally I prefer going into protostream (through iPhoto on mac) select all and delete from photostream if I have already imported pictures form camera roll (or photostream itself).